# Compare utils for Comparators

Tags: java, compare, comparator

Sometimes I have to compare a list of my POJOs using more than a single field, for example, first by a `boolean isExternal()` field and then by a `String getName()` field.

I wonder if there are known compare utility for doing that?

Code Snippet:

```
    @Override
    public int compare( CompanyProject o1, CompanyProject o2 ) {
        return CompareBuilder.compareBoolean(o1.isExternal(), o2.isExternal()).compareString(o1.getName(), o2.getName()).getResult();
    }
```

Don't want to write a bicycle :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want Apache Commons Lang [`CompareToBuilder`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html).

Comment: @omickron Actually, the Guava solution is probably better if it short-circuits. The Commons Lang stuff is classic but aging.

Comment: Apache Commons Lang looks closer to me :)

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 has some functions that allow construction and chaining of Comparators:

```
Comparator.comparing(Pojo::isExternal)
          .thenComparing(Pojo::getName);
```

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Thank's, I didn't mention, I need a solution for Java 7.

Comment: At least you're on 7. I answered a question from a guy recently who was stuck on 1.4. :-(

Comment: Poor guy! I'm really sorry for that people who had to support 1.4 or 1.5 versions.

Comment: Updated link  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 6):

Try Guava's [`ComparisonChain`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CommonObjectUtilitiesExplained#compare/compareTo):

```
public int compareTo(Foo that) {
     return ComparisonChain.start()
         .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
         .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
         .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
         .result();
```